# Why (true && true) raise an error while (1 && 1) doesn't?

Tags: c, logical-operators

I thought that C interpreted `true` as `1` but now I'm having doubts.

Full code (compiled with GCC 5.1):

```
if(true && true) // Error: 'true' undeclared (first use in this function)
{
}
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: To use the `true` and `false` macros in `C` (they are not reserved words), you need to include the [stdbool.h header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/boolean).

Comment: @tadman yes, but both are integers and because of that comparable or not?

Comment: Only if you give the compiler a hint, as in include the right header file.

Comment: @tadman It does have a boolean type. It's called `_Bool`. We need macros to rename it to `bool` because C *used to* not have a boolean type and people *used to* write macros to fake it, so all the `bool`-things are made opt-in so collisions are avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`true` is not a keyword in C like it is in C++.

To access it you'll have to `#include <stdbool.h>`.

Comment: Note that `true`, `false`, and `bool` May become keywords in C2x.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yay! Can't wait.